# Capturar IP de visitante num site WordPress em ficheiro.txt

Tags: wordpress, log, ip

Estou a tentar registar o IP, o Referrer e a data de ligação de todos os visitantes do meu site Wordpress num ficheiro.txt, mas não estou a ser bem sucessedido.

Já tentei com o Plugin '*WebRTC IP Grabber & Logger (STUN VPNs)*', mas este apenas regista o IP do próprio servidor onde se encontra o site.

Já procurei em bastantes sites e fóruns a mesma questão, mas também sem sucesso, pois não faço a menor ideia de como adicionar scripts.php as minhas páginas de modo a conseguir este efeito, e também me parece não haver outros Plugins (gratuitos) com a mesma funcionalidade.

Então a minha questão embora pareça '*duplicado*' é...

Como faço para registar toda esta informação num ficheiro.txt?

OU..

Como faço para extraír esta informação do phpMyAdmin para um ficheiro.txt?

Comment: Você não tem um log de acessos no servidor? Em servidores Nginx essas normalmente ficam em `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

Answer (score 1):

Copiando e colando códigos encontrados no SO e WPSE, segue um plugin bem simples para fazer isso. Adicionei uma função para capturar o tipo de página sendo vista (home, category, search, tag, etc). O plugin funciona no `wp_head` e é disparado em todas as páginas do *frontend* sendo visitadas.

O ficheiro de texto é gerado/armazenado dentro de `http://example.com/wp-content/ficheiro.txt`. Pessoalmente, acho que seria preferivel armazenar isso no banco de dados.

```
<?php
/** 
  * Plugin Name: (B5F) Capturar IP para ficheiro.txt
  * Version: 1.0
  * Author: brasofilo
  */

# https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83896
function wpse8170_loop() {
    global $wp_query;
    $loop = 'notfound';

    if ( $wp_query->is_page ) {
        $loop = is_front_page() ? 'front' : 'page';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_home ) {
        $loop = 'home';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_single ) {
        $loop = ( $wp_query->is_attachment ) ? 'attachment' : 'single';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_category ) {
        $loop = 'category';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_tag ) {
        $loop = 'tag';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_tax ) {
        $loop = 'tax';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_archive ) {
        if ( $wp_query->is_day ) {
            $loop = 'day';
        } elseif ( $wp_query->is_month ) {
            $loop = 'month';
        } elseif ( $wp_query->is_year ) {
            $loop = 'year';
        } elseif ( $wp_query->is_author ) {
            $loop = 'author';
        } else {
            $loop = 'archive';
        }
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_search ) {
        $loop = 'search';
    } elseif ( $wp_query->is_404 ) {
        $loop = 'notfound';
    }

    return $loop;
}

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/13646735
function getUserIP() {
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


add_action('wp_head', function(){
    $ip = getUserIP();
    $current_page = wpse8170_loop();
    $print = $ip . ' | ' . $current_page; // <--- PERSONALIZAR
    $logs = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/ficheiro.txt';
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/24972441
    $myfile = file_put_contents($logs, $print . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

No phpMyadmin procure a tabela que possui os ips. 
seguida procure pelo botão exportar. ele vai exportar a tabela completa em um aquivo que voc~e pode colocar on me antes de baixar tipo : ip.sql, dai é so renomear o arquivo ip.sql para ip.txt. eu uso o sublime text para ver o arquivo e apagar o que eue não vou precisar.

esse link explica como vc faz isso:
https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-export-a-database-using-phpmyadmin/